# How to make modifiers not auto-apply or update live while changing parameters?

Tags: modifiers, interface

I have a very big piece of mesh that I want to apply modifiers to. Let's use the example of Laplacian Smoothing.

Here's what I'd like to happen:

- Import my STL mesh and select it
- Load the "Laplacian Smoothing modifier."
- Change some parameters, e.g. change "Factor" to 0.5, "Repeat" to 10, and uncheck "Preserve volume."
- Hit "apply," wait an hour for it to compute, and see the result

However, here's what actually happens: when I load the modifier, it immediately automatically applies the modifier to the object based on the default parameters. This takes a long time because my mesh is huge, and meanwhile I never even wanted to see what my object looked like with the default smoothing, I wanted to change the parameters first. Then I change the "Factor" parameter, and as soon as I click in the next box to change another parameter, it automatically updates/calculates *again* - no, please stop, I still need to change another parameter! So I have to wait another hour before changing the next parameter. Basically this results in numerous lengthy, undesired computations, and it seems unnecessary to me.

So is there a way to suppress the calculation of a modifier until I say so? I.e. make it NOT apply in a "live update" sort of way, but instead, let me change the parameters first, without updating the mesh, and then only compute when I hit "Apply"?

I've seen some questions around here regarding using python scripts to apply modifiers. It seems like a python script may be one way of doing what I want. If it's the only way then I'll have to learn me some python scripting.

But to be clear - and this is why I think this is not a repeat question - I'm wondering if there's another way using the GUI to achieve this. Some kind of checkbox or option in Blender that says something like "don't auto-update when using modifiers, only compute when user hits Apply." I looked around and didn't see anything like that in Blender.

Comment: You could try to enter Edit mode of the object, and add modifier from there. **Laplacian Smooth** by default is disabled in Edit mode, so it should be added easily. It may not work in case of modifiers which *are* enabled in Edit mode though.

Comment: Mr Zak: That did work! For Laplacian Smooth, at least. It's not a totally universal solution, but for Laplacian Smooth it is a very quick and easy solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Set modifier on a simple object and then transfer it to a more complex one**

Use an "host" object to set up your modifier with the wanted
   parameters (e.g. a simple plane/a cube/a vertex..).

Once the modifier is added, **switch its 3D vieport visibility off** to prevent calculations.

Once satisfied with the settings, select both objects, make the "host" object the active object and then **Link the modifier** to the other by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choosing Modifiers from the pop up menu.

[image]

The modifier will be transferred **with all his settings**, even its "non visbility", to the selected objects, so you'll just have to **apply it** and wait for the end of the calculations.

[image]

Comment: This worked, thank you. Mr Zak's "edit mode" suggestion in a comment to my original question also works in this case, but as he pointed out it's not universal; your solution should work for every modifier.

Answer (score 0):

On the modifiers that have the option (such as subsurface) lower the "View" parameter.
Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While this does work for preventing subsequent auto-updates as I change parameters, it does not prevent the modifier from auto-calculating immediately upon being added. So I'm still stuck with the long calculation when I first load it.